# How to get user data from cloud store firebase in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

can you help me with getting data from Cloudstore Database?

```
SetUserData(user: User) {
    const inputName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: inputName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    });
}
```

Here I store info, but i can`t get it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, inject AngularFirestore into the constructor.

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}
```

Assuming your collection is called users:

```
onReadCollection() {
  this.db.collection(
      "users",
      ref => ref.where("uid", "<=", 5)
          .orderBy("uid")
  ).get()
      .subscribe(snaps => {
          snaps.forEach(snap => {
             console.log(snap.data());
          })
      });
}
```

This will return your users with uid <=5. You can edit the code as you like